# Converting a Django binary field to an array

Tags: python, arrays, django, oracle, blob

I use Django with a legacy Oracle database. In this database is a array saved as blob which I want to read with Django. The Model class was automatic created by using the `manage.py inspectdb` command.

```
class myTable(models.Model):
     myRow = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)
```

How can I convert the binary field to an array?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Django's model_to_dict to get the modeldata in a dict and then convert the dict to a list/array. from django.forms.models import model_to_dict,  model_to_dict(instance, fields=['myRow',( + additional fields that you want to include)]

Comment: I tried it and model_to_dict returned an empty dict. The data stored in the field is binary encoded. How should this function now what is a key or a value?

Comment: It should return a dict with the fieldname/object as key and the fieldvalues as its values. If you have multiple fields it returns a multiplekeydict. If there's data in the field it should be returned, try the code without the fields list, see docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/forms/models/. A second alternative is to filter which also returns a dict alike models_to_dict; filtered_dict =myTable.objects.values('myRow')

Comment: from django.forms.models import model_to_dict, in views; instance = myTable(), print model_to_dict(instance), returns {u'myRow': ..fieldcontent}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct) module in python. 
In my case a vector packed in the myRow binary field was represented as follows:

```
32 bit encoding | 32 bit number of elemnets (n) | n * encoding size
```

E.g. for a double vector:

```
    from struct import *

def getBlobVectorValues(blobData, formatStr):
    return unpack_from(formatStr,blobData, offset=8)

def getBlobVectorSize(blobData):
    blobSize = unpack_from('!I',blobData, offset=4)
    return blobSize[0]

def readBlob(blobData):
    blobEncoding = unpack_from('!I',blobData, offset=0)
    formatStr = "!"

    if (blobEncoding[0] == 23):       #encoding vector<double> 

        vectorSize = getBlobVectorSize(blobData)       
        for x in range(0, vectorSize):
            formatStr += "d"

    else:
        raise ValueError("Unexpected blob encoding: %d" % blobEncoding[0])

    return getBlobVectorValues(blobData,formatStr)
```